# Change button background on click and other buttons should be in previous color

Tags: android

I have 3 buttons with an image and below text. I want to change the background color of the button on click. If I clicked first button then its color should change into green color and the other buttons should be in yellow color. If I clicked second button then second button should in green color and other two should be yellow.

Is there any way to do this?

`MainActivity.java`

```
    Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bthomeprofile);
    Button friend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btfriendsprofile);
    Button office = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btofficeprofile);
    /*home.setOnClickListener(this);
    friend.setOnClickListener(this);
    office.setOnClickListener(this);*/

    public void onClick(View v)
{


    if(v.getId()== R.id.bthomeprofile )  
    {
         isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked;
         v.setBackgroundResource(isButtonClicked ? R.drawable.circle_button : R.drawable.button_color_change);
    }
    else if(v.getId()== R.id.btfriendsprofile)
    {
         isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked; 
         v.setBackgroundResource(isButtonClicked ? R.drawable.circle_button : R.drawable.button_color_change);
    }
    else if(v.getId()== R.id.btofficeprofile)
    {
         isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked; 
         v.setBackgroundResource(isButtonClicked ? R.drawable.circle_button : R.drawable.button_color_change);
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
    <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bthomeprofile"
                        android:layout_width="102dp"
                        android:layout_height="102dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                        android:src="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/homeicon"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Home"
                        android:textColor="#000000" 
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:onClick="homeProfile"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btfriendsprofile"
                        android:layout_width="102dp"
                        android:layout_height="102dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/friendsicon"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Friends"
                        android:textColor="#000000" 
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:onClick="friendsProfile"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btofficeprofile"
                        android:layout_width="102dp"
                        android:layout_height="102dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_button"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/officeicon"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Office"
                        android:textColor="#000000" 
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:onClick="officeProfile"/>

                </LinearLayout>
```

`circle_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="1000dp" />
    <solid android:color="#32c24d" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#c88f08" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMXSt.png)

Comment: There is a way to do that but what have you tried so far?

Comment: up your code which you tried to do this

Comment: U just need to set Background color of each button in an click function with respect to their button names like b1,b2,b3 for each button click..one by one

Comment: Kindly go through the edited post.

Comment: Please do not completely edit the post to remove the useful content. I've rolled back the version for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just keep a reference of previousButtonClicked

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);  
Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);  
Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);   
Button previousButton = null;
```

set all buttons background to yellow

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

       //set Background color Green to b1
       if(previousButton != null){
              //setBackGround color Yellow to previousButton
        }
        previousButton = b1;
     }
});
```

Do this in onClickListener of other buttons also.
In your Case

```
Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bthomeprofile);
Button friend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btfriendsprofile);
Button office = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btofficeprofile);
Button previousClickedButton = null;

public void onClick(View v){

    if(v.getId()== R.id.bthomeprofile){
         //set color to green
         //do your stuf  
    }
    else if(v.getId()== R.id.btfriendsprofile){
        //set color to green
        //do your stuff
    }
    else if(v.getId()== R.id.btofficeprofile){
        //set color to green
        //do your stuff
    }

    if(previousClickedButton != null){
        //setColor to yellow
    }
    previousClickedButton = (Button)v;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but not working. Kindly go through my edited post.

Comment: No change in color

Comment: how are u setting color?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using state drawable and assign that to your's 3 buttons.

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_sel" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_sel" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_unsel" />
</selector>
```